# Return key after posting (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a db object :

```
class form_info(db.Model):
    salary = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    curr_age = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    retire_age = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    goal = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
```

The posting method for this is as follows:

```
    def post(self):
        self.form_info=form_info(salary=int(self.request.get("salary")),curr_age=int(self.request.get("age")),retire_age=int(self.request.get("age_retire")),goal=int(self.request.get("goal")))
        self.form_info.put()
        self.redirect("/")
```

Is there a way to return the key of the object after posting? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the post method you can get the key of the object:

```
key = self.form_info.put()
```

If you're looking for actually returning the key value from the post method you should look at this Q&A : [What REST PUT/POST/DELETE calls should return by a convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268707/what-rest-put-post-delete-calls-should-return-by-a-convention)

If you're looking for a way to share the value across requests (i.e. making it available to the redirected get request) you should look at this Q&A : [Passing data between pages in a redirect() function in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134540/passing-data-between-pages-in-a-redirect-function-in-google-app-engine)