# can't update datastore in google-apps-engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-cloud-datastore, datastore, google-app-engine-python

I created a datastore object similarly to the guestbook tutorial:

```
class myDS(ndb.Model):
    a = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
```

And I have an Handlers to access it and update is:

```
class Handler1:

    my_ds = myDS()
    my_ds.a = "abc" #Trying to update the value

class Handler2:
    my_ds = myDS()
    self.response.write(my_ds.a) #Trying to access my_ds.aafter it was updated in Handlers1

def main():
   application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
           ('/set',   Handler1),
           ('/get',   Handler2])
```

I call:

```
Myapp.com/set 
Myapp.com/get : Prints None (Didn't update to "abc")
```

Why wasn't the value of a updated?
How can I update across the handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note is that in `Handler1` your code doesn't actually save the entity to the datastore, for that you need to invoke the `.put()` method:

```
my_ds = myDS()
my_ds.a = "abc" #Trying to update the value
my_ds_key = my_ds.put()  # save my_ds to the datastore and get its key
```

The second thing to note is that in `Handler2` the `my_ds = myDS()` call doesn't retrieve an entity from the datastore as you might expect, it just creates a *new* entity instead (which is also not saved to the datastore). To retrieve an entity from the datastore you need to do a lookup by the entity's key (or obtain it via a query):

```
my_ds = my_ds_key.get()
```

These are very basic concepts about using the datastore, you probably need to get more familiar with them. You should go through [Creating, Retrieving, Updating, and Deleting Entities](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities) (and maybe other related chapters grouped under the `Google Cloud Datastore` section in the left side navigation bar in that doc page)

Finally, to be able to make such lookup you need to somehow be able to  determine or transfer the entity key obtained in `Handler1` to `Handler2` as each request to these handlers is independent from each-other. Possibly of interest: [Passing data between pages in a redirect() function in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134540/passing-data-between-pages-in-a-redirect-function-in-google-app-engine)

Example of passing the key's string representation via `webapp2` sessions:

In `Handler1`

```
my_ds_key = my_ds.put()  # save my_ds to the datastore and get its key
self.session['urlsafe'] = my_ds_key.urlsafe()
```

In `Handler2`

```
urlsafe = self.session.get('urlsafe')
if urlsafe:        
    my_ds = ndb.Key(urlsafe=urlsafe).get()
```

Example of passing the key's string representation using a URL query string like `/get?urlsafe=<key's urlsafe representation>` (maybe hashed if you want, as it will be visible in the browser):

In `Handler1`

```
my_ds_key = my_ds.put()  # save my_ds to the datastore and get its key
self.redirect('/get?urlsafe=%s' % my_ds_key.urlsafe())
```

In `Handler2`

```
urlsafe = self.request.get('urlsafe')
if urlsafe:        
    my_ds = ndb.Key(urlsafe=urlsafe).get()
```

Example of getting the entity in `Handler2` via a query (the example assumes the right entity is returned by the query)

```
results = myDS().query().fetch(limit=1)
if results:
    my_ds = results[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, One thing I didn't understand - How can I call in Handler2 to the specific entity I edited in Handler1?

Comment: See the post I mentioned in the last paragraph.

Comment: I saw the post but it is not enough - even if I use put() in Handler1 I need to have the key in Handler2 - But Handler2 can't know the key from Handler1, couldn't understand how to overcome this problem