# Google appengine - user authentication with different versions

Tags: google-app-engine

Can different version within same google appengine project share same user sessions if its managed through users API? if not is there way user sessions can be shared between different versions?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing session info across different service versions is fundamentally equivalent to sharing it across different services.

If the session information is stored on the client side yes, it's possible - I am sharing session info (webapp2-based, see [Webapp2 Sessions in Google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997215/webapp2-sessions-in-google-app-engine)) across all my services this way.

If you use server-side session info storage (memcache/datastore) then it *may* be possible, if you're consistent in accessing it.

But, regardless of storing the info client or server-side, you still need to take care of different services/versions overwriting each-other's values - that's inherent from sharing the same session store.